# Python unit tests for dictionaries of dataframes

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a function that returns dictionaries of pandas dataframes and I wish to design a unit test for it.

I know how to unit-test equality over pandas dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal
import unittest

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6], 'c': [7,8,9]}) 
df2 =pd.DataFrame(df1)

class DictEq(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_dict_eq(self):
        assert_frame_equal(df1, df2)

unittest.main()
```

However, I do not seem to grasp how to design a test that compares the following:

```
dict1 = {'a': df1}
dict2 = {'a': df2}
```

I have tried the following, all of which fail:

```
from nose.tools import assert_equal, assert_dict_equal  

class DictEq(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_dict_eq1(self):
        assert_equal(dict1, dict2)

    def test_dict_eq2(self):
        assert_dict_equal(dict1 , dict2)

    def test_dict_eq3(self):
        self.assertTrue(dict1 == dict2)
```

assert_dict_equal function of pandas.util.testing fails as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6], 'c': [7,8,9]})
df2 =pd.DataFrame(df1)

class DfWrap():
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
    def __eq__(self, df2):
        return all(self.df == df2)


dic1 = {'a': DfWrap(df1)}
dic2 = {'a': DfWrap(df2)}

print(dic1 == dic2)
```

This outputs `True`. It should work with `assert_dict_equal` as well, as long as you wrap your `dataframe` objects in `DfWrap`.

**Here's why it works:**

You have to imagine that in order to compare dictionaries, python will go through each key (recursively) and call `__eq__` (or `==`) on the items to compare. The problem is that when you call `__eq__` (or `==`) on a `dataframe`, it doesn't return a `bool`. Instead it returns another `dataframe`:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6], 'c': [7,8,9]})
df2 =pd.DataFrame(df1)

df_compare = df1 == df2
print(type(df_compare))
```

this outputs:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

So, instead, the wrapper makes it so that doing `df1 == df2` outputs a `bool` instead of a `dataframe`:

```
DfWrap(df1) == DfWrap(df2)
```

evaluates to `True`.

HTH.

Comment: Thank you for an elegant solution. I called my test with self.assertTrue(dict1_bis == dict2_bis) , after applying dict1_bis = {key : DfWrap(value) for key, value in dict1.iteritems()} and it works as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but you may do something like this:

```
import unittest


class DictEq(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_dict_eq1(self):
        dict1 = {'a': df1}
        dict2 = {'a': df2}
        key1 = dict1.keys()
        key2 = dict2.keys()
        self.assertEqual(key1,key2) 
        for key, val in dict1.items():
            df1 = dict1[key]
            df2 = dict2[key]
            assert_frame_equal(df1, df2)
```

Comment: `dict1[key]` will return 2 and and `dict2[key]` will return 3. So you are literally trying to compare 2 and 3. Is that what you want to showcase?

Comment: @mad_ thanks for noting the issue. no I meant ``` dict1 = {'a': df1}
dict2 = {'a': df2} ```. this is what was mentioned in question.

Comment: @Farbood have you tested this function? I am just trying to run the inner logic but it keeps failing over.

Comment: @mad_ I have tested it. Can you explain more?

Comment: sorry was referring to the wrong `df1` as was not there in your piece of code. You are fine. Code does make sense

Comment: I am not sure this will always work : key1 and key2 are lists, and there is no reason that they are ordered in the same way. Changing this to set(key1) and set(key2) should do the trick , though.